# React Context Value always returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am new to working with contexts and I'm just trying to start slow. I saw a thing about logging your Provider to test the value and I am getting a constant undefined value. I have moved them right next to each other in the code to see if that changes anything.

```
const PromptContext = createContext('test123');
```

```
function generateRecipe() {
    <PromptContext.Provider value="hello">xxx</PromptContext.Provider>
    console.log(PromptContext.Provider.value);
    console.log("Generating recipe...");
  }
}
```

Upon this function being called the log value is always undefined, no matter what is put in the value of the Provider. Any ideas on fixing this?

The end goal is to get the value of the provider into this consumer which is in a separate react file

```
<PromptContext.Consumer>
    {test => (
        <h1>{test.value}</h1>
    )}
</PromptContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: I've never seen accessing context value like this `PromptContext.Provider.value`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I highly recommend using a proper debugger or the React Dev Tools browser extension. Logging for debugging purposes is easily misinterpreted

Comment: Your function doesn't do anything with the JSX element; it's basically a no-op. It's entirely unclear what you're trying to do. Typically, to access a context value you use the `useContext()` hook within a component that is a child of the context provider. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: Sorry, I added an edit that hopefully provides some more context on what I am trying to do.

Comment: Shouldn't the `Provider` wrap completely around everything that may consume via the `Consumer` / `useContext`?

Comment: I think you should go back to the documentation and start again with some simple examples... https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 1):

Your provider should not be part of a function (in the way you have it listed, anyway). The provider, of course, WILL be a function, but you aren't going to just be including it inside functions in the same way you showed above. It's actually easier than that!

You want it like this:

```
export const PromptContext = createContext();

export const PromptContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  // All of your logic here
  const baseValue = 'hello';

  return (
    <PromptContext.Provider value={{baseValue}}>
      {children}
    </PromptContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

You don't mix the provider with your end function like you're doing above.

Instead, in your index.js file, you'll wrap your component:

```
root.render(
  <PromptContextProvider>
    <App />
  </PromptContextProvider>
)
```

And then you can access your `baseValue` by using `const {baseValue} = useContext(PromptContext)` in your components.

Comment: This seems simple, I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

[React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) uses the component hierarchy to make state broadly available.

You create a provider with a value and use that to *wrap* other components. Anything in the component tree under the provider can then access the context value using either [Context.Consumer](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer) or the [useContext()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook.

For example

```jsx
const PromptContext = createContext('test123');

const App = () => (
  <PromptContext.Provider value="hello">
    <ChildWithConsumer />
    <ChildWithHook />
  </PromptContext.Provider>
);

const ChildWithConsumer = () => (
  <PromptContext.Consumer>
    {(prompt) => (
      <p>The context says "{prompt}"</p>
    )}
  </PromptContext.Consumer>
);

const ChildWithHook = () => {
  const prompt = useContext(PromptContext);

  return (
    <p>The context says "{prompt}"</p>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit bold-margulis-uh1by8]